# Trouble with Minimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
Minimize[{t^2, 1 == 3*t + 16*u}, {t, u}, Integers]
```

1. It does not give the solution  t = -5   and   u = 1.
2. Am I missing something?

The solution being known and easy, the actual question is not "how can I minimize?"; it is rather "how is it that *Mathematica*, even version 8 or 9, can't do it?"

Comment: Recall Bézout's identity: `ExtendedGCD[3, 16] // Last`.

Comment: Interesting, If you put Abs[t] instead of t^2 it gives the result which is obviously the same.

Comment: Interesting.. `Minimize[(14*c + 11)^2, c, Integers]` gives `{9, {c -> -1}}` while `Minimize[(15*c + 11)^2, c, Integers]` returns unevaluated..